# Incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct PartyInfo' from type Int

Tags: c, types

```
int main() {

struct PartyInfo maxVoteParty;
maxVoteParty = maxVoteParty = GetMaxVote(partiesInfo, noPartyLists);

printf("\n");

return 0;
}

struct PartyInfo GetMaxVote(struct PartyInfo array[], int partyListNumber)
{
    int maxVote = 0;
    int i;
    struct PartyInfo maxVoteParty;

    for (i = 0; i < partyListNumber; i++)
    {
        if (maxVote == 0 || maxVote < array[i].votes)
        {
            maxVote = array[i].votes;
            maxVoteParty = array[i];
        }
    }

    return maxVoteParty;
}
```

Hello,

I receive the above error on the following line:

```
maxVoteParty = maxVoteParty = GetMaxVote(partiesInfo, noPartyLists);
```

I am extremely new to C but have used Java, C#, Python and a bunch of other languages quite extensively, i've run into loads of new problems with C.

Comment: put prototype `struct PartyInfo GetMaxVote(struct PartyInfo array[], int partyListNumber);` before `int main() {`

Comment: this line: `maxVoteParty = maxVoteParty = GetMaxVote(partiesInfo, noPartyLists);` is probably not correct as it has `maxVoteParty` being assigned to itself.

Comment: when assigning one struct to another struct, of the same type, use either: `memcpy()` or assign each field individually.

Comment: it is 'usually' best to pass pointers to structs, not pass the whole struct.

Comment: several of the parameters being passed to GetMaxVote() are not defined within the posted code, so we cannot debug this compile problem.  what is the definition of `struct PartyInfo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a function prototype for GetMaxVote function before the first actual call of the function.

```
struct PartyInfo GetMaxVote(struct PartyInfo array[], int partyListNumber);
```